# Python: Need help creating dictionaries from text files and splitting a list

Tags: python, file, list, dictionary

I want to save data in text files and create dictionaries from those files, which I'll pass to a function later on.

Here's my code:

```
def lesson_dictionary(filename):
    print "Reading file ", filename
    with open(filename) as f:
        mylist = f.read().strip().split() 
        dictionary = OrderedDict(zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2])) #keep keys/values in same order as declared in mylist
        print dictionary
    return dictionary
```

With a sample file named sample.txt containing two columns of key/value pairs separated by a space, it works fine. For example,

a b

c d

e f

yields a list like so:

```
OrderedDict([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')])
```

BUT if I change the code and the content of the .txt file, it breaks. For example, if sample2.txt included:

a:b

c:d

e:f

and my code is

```
def lesson_dictionary(filename):
    print "Reading file ", filename
    with open(filename) as f:
        mylist = f.read().strip().split(':') #CHANGED: split string at colon!
        dictionary = OrderedDict(zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2]))
        print dictionary
    return dictionary
```

I get the following output:

```
OrderedDict([('a', 'b \nc'), ('d\ne', 'f')])
```

What's happening? Why did strip() work for the first .txt file but not for the second? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original `split()` split on whitespace, and `\n` is considered whitespace. By changing to `split(':')` you've removed the split on the end of line, so the end of one line is merged with the start of the next with an extra newline character in the middle. I don't think there's an easy way to fix it except to read the file one line at a time.

Edit: Some code to demonstrate.

```
dictionary = OrderedDict()
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split(':')
        dictionary[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

Or more in the spirit of your original:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    mylist = [line.strip().split(':') for line in f]
    dictionary = OrderedDict(mylist)
```

The second form has the disadvantage of not automatically stripping whitespace from around the words. Based on your example, you might need that.

Comment: i would really recommend the alternative mark suggests "...except to read the file one line at a time." Letting the file object split the lines e.g. `for line in f` would  be more readable.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the explanation and the example code, Mark.

Answer (score 2):

`split()` without a separator splits on whitespace, which is both newlines and tabs/spaces. When you `split` on a colon, that algorithm no longer applies, so newlines show up in your output. Try:

```
dictionary = Ordereddict(l.strip().split(':') for l in f)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this explanation, @spinlok. Your sample code worked and is tremendously helpful. It's also simple and straightforward. Is there an advantage to doing it on one line as opposed to the way Mark did?

Comment: @user1186742, doing it this way uses half the memory since you don't create a list all at once, you get a generator which feeds the OrderedDict one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the input files yourself, I believe [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) would be better suited for this problem.

You can use it like this:

```
import json

#write the dictionary to a file
outfile = open(filename, 'w')
json.dump(someDictionary, outfile)

#read the data back in
with open(filename) as infile:
    newDictionary = json.load(infile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing out the contents of `myList`?

```
myList = ["a", "b c", "d e", "f"]
```

Replace the colons with spaces first if you want them to behave the same way:

```
myList = f.read().replace(":", "").split()
```

Or, if you want the split them into key value pairs, just use string slicing to zip even and odd elements together:

```
s = f.read().split()
myDict = dict(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be **delimiter neutral**, i.e `a:b`, `a-b`, `a#b` and such. Instead of regular `split()` use `re.split()`.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"[^\w]")     # non-w char
with open(filename, "rt") as fr:
    return OrderedDict(pattern.split(l.strip()) for l in fr)
```